# VF : Persist data between two VF pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, amazon-s3

This is my VF Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" cache="false" contentType="text/html" controller="AWS_Upload"  >

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id ="mainContent">
    <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Category : </span> <select id="selectid" name="filecategory">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
           </select>
          <br /><br />
     <form action="https://kvntest1.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
        <input type="hidden"  name="key"  id="key" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{!awsKeySet.AWS_AccessKey_Id__c}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="policy" value="{!policy}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="signature" value="{!signedPolicy}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="acl" value="{!acessType}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="{!Content_Type}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{!ForRedirect}" />





        <h4 class="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload in AWS</h4><br />
        <div class="row">
              <input type="file" size="50" name="file" id="file" onchange="fileSelected();" />
        </div>

        <div id="fileName"></div>
        <div id="fileSize"></div>
        <div id="fileType"></div>

        <div class="row">
          <input type="submit" value="Upload"  id="btn_submit" />
        </div>
       <div id="progressNumber"></div>
    </form> 
    </div>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () { 

                var _requestBucket;

                $("#btn_submit").click(function(event){
                    //alert(1);
                        event.preventDefault();
                      var _file;

                    _file = $("#file").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, "");

                   // console.log('_file'+_file);
                    $("#key").val(_file);
                    var bla1 = $('#selectid').val();
                    $("#cate").val(bla1);
                   $("#uploadForm").submit(); 


                });

                $("#selectid").change(function(){
                   //alert('change called');
                   $("input[name='fc']").val($(this).val());
                   var bla = $('#selectid').val();
                   console.log('~~~ var : '+ bla);



                });



         });


    </script>

</apex:page>
```

This is the redirect VF Page.

```
<apex:page controller="AWS_Upload" >
 <script> 

        AWS_Upload.createNewDocument('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.parentIdForRedirect}','{!$CurrentPage.parameters.key}',
                                                '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.bucket}','{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cate}',function(result,event){
                    if (event.status) {




                                 console.log('Result Id == '+ result.Id);
                                 CallApexMethod();


                    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                        alert('Something wrong happened' );
                    } else {
                       alert('Something wrong happened' );
                    } 



 })

</script>
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!pageredir}">
<apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!dp}" value="" />


</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

This is my controller markup

```
public with sharing class AWS_Upload {
   public  Document__c newDocument{get;set;}
   Public  static AWS_Keys1__c awsKeySet{get;set;}
   public string ForRedirect{get;set;}  
   public static string appParentId{get;set;}
   public string Content_Type {get;set;}  
   Public String acessType{get;set;}
   public String sigver{get;set;}
   public String dp{get;set;}
   public  String catvar{get;set;}

   public AWS_Upload(){
      //newDocument = new Document__c();
      //newDocument.Category__c = 'A';
      catvar = 'A';
       awsKeySet= AWS_Keys1__c.getInstance('KVPUPLOAD');
        appParentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parentIdForRedirect');
        ForRedirect = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+'apex/AWS_SucessRedirectPage?parentIdForRedirect='+appParentId+'&cate='+catvar;
       Content_Type ='multipart/form-data';
       acessType ='public-read-write';


       system.debug('awsKeySet'+awsKeySet); 
        system.debug('policy'+policy);
   }


       Datetime expire = system.now().addDays(1);
       String formattedexpire = expire.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd')+'T'+ expire.formatGmt('HH:mm:ss')+'.'+expire.formatGMT('SSS')+'Z';           

      string policy { 

get {

return 
        '{ "expiration": "'+formattedexpire+'","conditions": [ {"bucket": "kvntest1" } ,{ "acl": "'+acessType+'" },'+
        '{"content-type":"'+Content_Type+'"},'+
        '{"success_action_redirect": "'+ForRedirect+'"},' +
        '["starts-with", "$key",""] ]}';   

}
 } 



    public String getPolicy() {
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));
    }

    public String getSignedPolicy() {    
        return make_sig(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy)));        
    }


    //method that will sign
    private String make_sig(string canonicalBuffer) {        
        String macUrl ;

        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', blob.valueof(canonicalBuffer),blob.valueof(awsKeySet.AWS_Secret_Key__c));
        macUrl = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);                
        return macUrl;

    }



     @RemoteAction
    public static Document__c createNewDocument(String appID, String uploadedFilename,string bucketName, String category){
         //stem.debug('ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters() '+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parentIdForRedirect')); 
        Document__c newDocument = new Document__c();
           newDocument.Application__c = appID;
            newDocument.Document_Name__c = uploadedFilename;
            //newDocument.Document_URL__c =  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'+bucketName+'/'+uploadedFilename;
            newDocument.Document_URL__c =  'https://kvntest1.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/'+uploadedFilename;
            newDocument.Download_Link__c = 'https://kvntest1.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/'+uploadedFilename;
            newDocument.Category__c = category;
            newDocument.Status__c ='Uploaded';

         insert  newDocument;

         return newDocument;  

    }


    public PageReference pageredir()
    {
        System.debug('~~~ pageredir invoked ');
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/a0J?fcf=00B0I00000AHJI3&rolodexIndex=-1&page=1');
        //PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + dp);
        return pageRef;
    }



}
```

This is how my VF page looks like

[image]

1.The user selects the category first before uploading the file.

2.Once the upload is done on AWS S3, it is then redirected to redirect VF Page.

3.The redirect VF page has a remoting method which creates a custom object Document__c which contains the URL of the uploaded file.

I am at my wits end as to how I persist the "category" value between the flow.

I am currently defaulting to "A" in the controller.

```
catvar = 'A';
```

Amazon file upload has to be in `<form>` tag which pretty much makes me not possible to use `<apex:form>` at all.

Without `<apex:form>` I can't use most of the VF tags like `<apex:actionFunction>,  <apex:inputHidden>, <apex:inputField>` etc

Also since the method to create a custom object (in the redirect VF page) is a remoting method, I cant even access non static variables in the controller.

Can anyone have any ideas to how to solve this ?

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Couldn't you write a simple demo of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @sfdcfox hi...brian..sure thing..I have removed the css frills/and other not used methods from the question. Let me know if you need anything further ...tx mate